# a function that accepts a string

Tags: r

I have a function that takes a string as an argument.
z <- p.str('0.002 0.003 0.555')

```
p.str <- function(mystr){
  
  p.ad <-  p.adjust(as.numeric(strsplit(mystr, " "))) #
  mystr<- as.numeric(strsplit(mystr, " ")) #
  rez <- paste(mystr,p.ad,collapse='\n') #
  
  return(rez)
}

z <- data.table(z)
```

`p.ad` - calculates adjusted values

`mystr` - string as we write it and translate it numeric

then I write to data.table.

I get an error: 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

what I expect:

```
|     z        |
|--------------|
|  0.002 0.006 |
|  0.003 0.006 |
|  0.555 0.555 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this function :

```
p.str <- function(mystr){
  vec <- as.numeric(strsplit(mystr, " ")[[1]])
  p.ad <-  p.adjust(vec) #
  rez <- paste(vec,p.ad,collapse='\n') 
  return(rez)
}

cat(p.str('0.002 0.003 0.555'))

#0.002 0.006
#0.003 0.006
#0.555 0.555
```

Answer (score 3):

`strsplit` returns a `list`. This is because it is vectorized, e.g., `strsplit(c("1 2", "3 4 5"), split = " ")`.

If you know the input character string will be of length 1, then you can safely use `unlist(strsplit(...))` or `strsplit(...)[[1]]`. You could also check that the input is of length 1.

Also, it's inefficient and bad practice to have `as.numeric(strsplit(mystr, " "))` repeated in your function. If you need to use that result more than once, assign it to an object.

```
p.str <- function(mystr){
  
  num  <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(mystr, " ")))
  p.ad <- p.adjust(num) 
  paste(num, p.ad, collapse='\n')

}
```